# How drag and drop of files is done?

Tags: c++, windows, drag-and-drop

as in winamp or vlc player, how to do a file drag and drop? i mean i want to know what sort of coding goes into application? i want to know for c++

Answer (score 15):

In pure C/C++ on Windows, start reading about the [DragAcceptFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776406(VS.85).aspx)  function and the [WM_DROPFILES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774303(VS.85).aspx) message. If you're using a more powerful C++ library (Qt, Wx, etc) check their respective documentation. It would help to know what you use, more specifically.

Also, [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190596/drag-and-drop-in-winapi) may answer your question. If it's what you meant, please close this question.

Answer (score 4):

With com:

Create a class that public extends IDropTarget

Register your class for drops. Do this in WM_CREATE

```
RegisterDragDrop(hwnd,static_cast<IDropTarget*>(pointer_to_your_class));
```

In your class you need to override a couple of functions since they are pure virtual:

```
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE DragEnter( 
        /* [unique][in] */ __RPC__in_opt IDataObject *pDataObj,
        /* [in] */ DWORD grfKeyState,
        /* [in] */ POINTL pt,
        /* [out][in] */ __RPC__inout DWORD *pdwEffect) = 0;

virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE DragOver( 
    /* [in] */ DWORD grfKeyState,
    /* [in] */ POINTL pt,
    /* [out][in] */ __RPC__inout DWORD *pdwEffect) = 0;

virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE DragLeave( void) = 0;

virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Drop( 
    /* [unique][in] */ __RPC__in_opt IDataObject *pDataObj,
    /* [in] */ DWORD grfKeyState,
    /* [in] */ POINTL pt,
    /* [out][in] */ __RPC__inout DWORD *pdwEffect) = 0;
```

Each of those functions will get called when those events occur, i.e. when someone pass the mouse in your window with a file DragEnter on your class will get called.

You will also need to implement a couple more functions that IDropTarget extends, check out IUnknown in your MSDN.

Then you need to query IDataObject param to get the data:

```
FORMATETC fdrop = {CF_HDROP, 0, DVASPECT_CONTENT, -1, TYMED_HGLOBAL};

if (SUCCEEDED(pDataObj->QueryGetData(&fdrop)) ){
    STGMEDIUM stgMedium = {0};
    stgMedium.tymed = TYMED_HGLOBAL;
    HRESULT hr = pDataObj->GetData(&fdrop, &stgMedium);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        HGLOBAL gmem = stgMedium.hGlobal;
        HDROP hdrop = (HDROP)GlobalLock(gmem);
        UINT numOfFiles =  DragQueryFile( (HDROP) hdrop,
                            0xFFFFFFFF,
                           NULL,
                            0
                        );

        TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH];
        for( int i=0;i<numOfFiles;i++ ){
            UINT charsCopied = DragQueryFile( (HDROP) hdrop,
                            i,
                           buffer,
                            MAX_PATH
                        );
            MessageBox(NULL,buffer,_T("Archivos a copiar: "),MB_OK);


        }
        // use str
        GlobalUnlock(gmem);


        /*TCHAR* str = (TCHAR*)GlobalLock(gmem);
        // use str
        GlobalUnlock(gmem);*/
        ::ReleaseStgMedium(&stgMedium);
    }

}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

**edit** *after* I posted this, the question was edited to qualify as C++; I'm going to leave this answer here for reference only.

---

"what sort off coding goes into application":

That depends hugely on the platform and language. For example, here are examples for Windows via [C#/.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307966/) or [VB/.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306969). For C++, Delphi, etc - the tricks will be different.

Comment: he explicitly asked about C++

Comment: No, he really didn't. Check the revisions, and check when I replied. The C++ tags and note were added later.

Answer (score 0):

You should use COM's Ole Drag and drop interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Before the days of OLE/COM/ActiveX, we would do something like the following:

- If we received a mouse down event,
  take note of cursor position.
- If we received a mouse movement and
  it moved a certain distance from the
  original point then we're starting a
  drag operation. Build a cursor that
  represents the object you're dragging
  (determined from the original cursor
  position).
- When we received a mouse down: if dragging never started then it's a click otherwise use the drop
  position to determine what to do with
  the object.

Note: none of this would allow you to drag objects between apps, just inside individual apps.