# C++ how do I clickdrag?

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to write a function to do right mouse button down click drag, but I can't seem to get it to work! Am I missing something here? thanks!

EDIT: it's not drag and drop of files. I am just moving the mouse cursor around while holding down the right mouse button

```
INPUT input;
input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
input.mi.dx = 0;
input.mi.dy = 0;
input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN;
input.mi.time = 0;
SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(input));

input.mi.dx = 500;
input.mi.dy = 0;
input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
input.mi.time = 0;
SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(input));
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How drag and drop of files is done](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449872/how-drag-and-drop-of-files-is-done/449943#449943)?

Comment: no, it's not drag and drop of files. I am just moving the mouse cursor around while holding down the right mouse button