# drag and drop through a filter

Tags: winapi, drag-and-drop

This is for Windows XP, 7 or 8. Any flavor. Programming in ANSI C and Win32.

I want to write a filter that is used to drag and drop but when being dropped it would ask for a new file name. The idea would be to drag a file to the filter (which may be on the desktop) then respond to the filter's prompt with a new name then continue with the drag and drop.

I have experimented with a .BAT file and determined that such a filter could be written. But with my experiment the drop occurs into the same folder from which the drag originated.

So my question has to do with continuing the drag after the new name is obtained.

I've tried checking into how to do that but have failed.

Does anyone have some pointers (documents, URL's, stackoverflow references, etc) that may lead me to understanding how to continue the drag and drop after obtaining a new name?

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating your own HWND that accepts drops via [`DragAcceptFiles()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776406.aspx) or [`RegisterDragDrop()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678405.aspx), then you are notified of a drop but are in full control over what the drop actually does.  Simply extract the dropped filenames to learn about the source files, then prompt the user for the destination filenames, and then copy the source files to the target files as needed.  You cannot change the source filenames that are being dropped, the dropped data is read-only.

If you are having trouble doing that, please provide the actual code you are having trouble with.

Comment: Thanks, I also found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345435/drag-and-drop-support-for-win32-gui

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal drag and drop from one folder to another. I want to add an extension to the file name as it is being dropped. The user would drop the file onto my application, the application would then add the new extension, then the application would let the drag and drop continue.

Think of it as if you drag from a folder to another folder then rename the dropped file by using F2. But I want the rename to be automated.

I don't have any source yet ... first I want to know if this is even possible.

Comment: You cannot "let the drag and drop continue". If the user drops onto your app, your app is responsible for processing the dropped data, not the filesystem.  Your app will have to create new files with the desired filenames. If the user drops directly onto a normal folder, another app, etc, your app will not be notified.

Comment: Thanks, I'll abandon that idea.